# How to get rid of "Unnamed: 0" column in a pandas DataFrame read in from CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a situation wherein sometimes when I read a `csv` from `df` I get an unwanted index-like column named `unnamed:0`.

`file.csv`

```
,A,B,C
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9
```

The CSV is read with this:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv')

   Unnamed: 0  A  B  C
0           0  1  2  3
1           1  4  5  6
2           2  7  8  9
```

This is very annoying! Does anyone have an idea on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Don't assume the CSV file was necessarily written out either in pandas or by the OP. (Often, the CSV came from some other user/tool/script, so they can't control its format.) Hence the `read_csv(..., index_col=[0])` workaround is the main thing, rather than "Do `pd.to_csv(..., index=False)`".

Answer (score 391, accepted):

It's the index column, pass `pd.to_csv(..., index=False)` to not write out an unnamed index column in the first place, see the [`to_csv()` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Example:

```
In [37]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv()))

Out[37]:
   Unnamed: 0         a         b         c
0           0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
1           1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252
2           2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283
3           3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101
4           4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
```

compare with:

```
In [38]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))

Out[38]:
          a         b         c
0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252
2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283
3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101
4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
```

You could also optionally tell `read_csv` that the first column is the index column by passing `index_col=0`:

```
In [40]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv()), index_col=0)

Out[40]:
          a         b         c
0  0.109066 -1.112704 -0.545209
1  0.447114  1.525341  0.317252
2  0.507495  0.137863  0.886283
3  1.452867  1.888363  1.168101
4  0.901371 -0.704805  0.088335
```

Comment: A lot of times the datasets you get from elsewhere already contain this column so it doesn't really help knowing how to produce the "right" dataset using the right parameters. Is there a way to eliminate this column when you load it when it's already there?

Comment: @CalvinKu unfortunately there is no `skipcols` arg for `read_csv`, after reading in the csv you could just do `df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[0])` or you could just read the columns in first and then pass the cols minus the first column something like `cols = pd.read_csv( ....., nrows=1).columns` and then re-read again `df = pd.read_csv(....., usecols=cols[1:])` this avoids the overhead of reading a superfluous column and then dropping it afterwards

Comment: It's better practice to include the square brackets in `read_csv(..., index_col=[0])`. Also avoids [tickling the whole pre-0.16.1 deprecated `index_col = False` bug](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.16.1.html).

Comment: @smci I saw similar solution posted by @cs95. Just wondering whey `index_col=[0]` is better than `index_col=0`?

Comment: @MrRobot: I posted the link above which tells you why: [`index_col = False` was deprecated way back in 0.16.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.16.1.html), and Python can't really tell the diference between `bool False` and `int 0`, so `index_col = 0` is deprecated too. Put list brackets around the zero: `[0]`.

Answer (score 121):

This is usually caused by your CSV having been saved along with an (unnamed) index (`RangeIndex`).

(The fix would actually need to be done when saving the DataFrame, but this isn't always an option.)

#### Workaround: `read_csv` with `index_col=[0]`  argument

IMO, the simplest solution would be to **read the unnamed column as the *index***. Specify an `index_col=[0]` argument to [**`pd.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), this reads in the first column as the index. (Note the square brackets).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame('x', index=range(5), columns=list('abc'))
df

   a  b  c
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
3  x  x  x
4  x  x  x

# Save DataFrame to CSV.
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv')

   Unnamed: 0  a  b  c
0           0  x  x  x
1           1  x  x  x
2           2  x  x  x
3           3  x  x  x
4           4  x  x  x

# Now try this again, with the extra argument.
pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=[0])

   a  b  c
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
3  x  x  x
4  x  x  x
```

> **Note**
> You could have avoided this in the first place by
> using `index=False` if the output CSV was created in pandas, if your DataFrame does not have an index to begin with:
>
> ```
> df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
> ```
>
> But as mentioned above, this isn't always an option.

---

#### Stopgap Solution: Filtering with `str.match`

If you cannot modify the code to read/write the CSV file, you can just **remove the column by filtering** with [**`str.match`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html):

```
df 

   Unnamed: 0  a  b  c
0           0  x  x  x
1           1  x  x  x
2           2  x  x  x
3           3  x  x  x
4           4  x  x  x

df.columns
# Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

df.columns.str.match('Unnamed')
# array([ True, False, False, False])

df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.match('Unnamed')]
 
   a  b  c
0  x  x  x
1  x  x  x
2  x  x  x
3  x  x  x
4  x  x  x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That `index_col=[0]` fix easily solved this annoying problem of 'unnamed:0' and spares code from verbose reinventing the wheel.

Comment: To get ride of Unnamed columns, you can also use regex such as `df.drop(df.filter(regex="Unname"),axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: The stopgap solution was relevant to my issue. Great answer!

Comment: I think the stopgap solution is the right one. If I have no assurance that the Unnamed column exists, I need to deal with both cases, and removing the first column every time is not an option.

Answer (score 37):

To get ride of all Unnamed columns, you can also use regex such as `df.drop(df.filter(regex="Unname"),axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: This worked really well for me as `str.match` above created `nans` for my column names that were date formatted.

Comment: I had the same problem with my data column names that had integers, this code solved the problem.

Answer (score 11):

Another case that this might be happening is if your data was improperly written to your `csv` to have each row end with a comma. This will leave you with an unnamed column `Unnamed: x` at the end of your data when you try to read it into a `df`.

Comment: I used `usecols=range(0,10)` to cut off the unnamed column

Comment: An example of this is having data such as `musical_instruments_store.csv`

`color,item\nbrown,piano,`

Either:
- you have a missing column on the first line (e.g price which is null in this case so it should've been `colour, item, price`) 
- Trailing comma on the second line so the data needs to be cleaned (so it should be `brown,piano` instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can do either of the following with 'Unnamed' Columns:

1. Delete unnamed columns
2. Rename them (if you want to use them)

#### Method 1: Delete Unnamed Columns

```
# delete one by one like column is 'Unnamed: 0' so use it's name
df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)

#delete all Unnamed Columns in a single code of line using regex
df.drop(df.filter(regex="Unnamed"),axis=1, inplace=True)
```

#### Method 2: Rename Unnamed Columns

`df.rename(columns = {'Unnamed: 0':'Name'}, inplace = True)`

If you want to write out with a blank header as in the input file, just choose 'Name' above to be ''.

where the OP's input data 'file.csv' was:

```
,A,B,C
0,1,2,3
1,4,5,6
2,7,8,9
```

#read file
`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: Only Method 2 worked for me. Thanks so much. Made my deadline!

Answer (score 4):

Simply delete that column using: `del df['column_name']`

Comment: This is probably the easiest way

Comment: @AnshumanKumar: no it's not, the easiest way is simply to use `read_csv(..., index_col=[0])`. Generally with pandas, trying to hack around an issue instead of taking 5 min to read the documentation then experimenting till you solve it only causes/defers further problems. Admittedly the pandas doc is unclear, incomplete, and lagging the code (welcome to open source!). That's what github is for.

Answer (score 4):

Simple do this:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
import io


df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=[0])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)))
display(df.head(5))
```

Comment: ```index_col=[0]``` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, there are many reasons you might not want to set that column as index_col =[0] as so many people suggest above. For example it might contain jumbled index values because data were saved to csv after being indexed or sorted without `df.reset_index(drop=True)` leading to instant confusion.

So if you know the file has this column and you don't want it, as per the original question, the simplest 1-line solutions are:

`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv').drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])`

or

`df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=[0]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is agnostic to whether the index has been written or not when utilizing `df.to_csv()` is shown below:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
if 'Unnamed: 0' in df.columns:
    df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

If an index was not written, then `index_col=[0]` will utilize the first column as the index which is behavior that one would not want.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was slightly different. The first header was unnamed, which caused all my data afterwards to shift left, making it misaligned, and made the last column all NaN.

I resolved it using the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', nrows=1)
columns = list(df.columns)[1:]
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows=1, header=None, names=columns)
```