# Pandas merge how to avoid unnamed column

Tags: python, pandas

There are two DataFrames that I want to merge:

```
DataFrame A columns: index, userid, locale  (2000 rows)  
DataFrame B columns: index, userid, age     (300 rows)
```

When I perform the following:

```
pd.merge(A, B, on='userid', how='outer')
```

I got a DataFrame with the following columns:

index, Unnamed:0, userid, locale, age

The `index` column and the `Unnamed:0` column are identical. I guess the `Unnamed:0` column is the index column of DataFrame B.

My question is: is there a way to avoid this `Unnamed` column when merging two DFs?

I can drop the `Unnamed` column afterwards, but just wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried setting index = False? There is a good discussion on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519086/pandas-how-to-get-rid-of-unnamed-column-in-a-dataframe

Comment: @datawrestler merge does not have a index argument. (to_csv has it but not merge)

Comment: Right, but if you set the flag when reading in each DF and then merge that might do it

Comment: @datawrestler the index was automatically set by the DF not by reading from a file.

Comment: can you share a sample of the data sets and the code used to arrive at the merge? I am sure we can find a solution to this!

Comment: @datawrestler sorry I cannot share the data but you can try to replicate the column structure. (I don't think the number of rows matters)

Comment: @Cheng, can you post an output of the following command: `print(A.columns.tolist()); print(B.columns.tolist())` __before__ merging?

Comment: @MaxU A's list ['Unnamed: 0', 'userid', 'locale'], B's list ['userid', 'age'].

Comment: please read carefully the first link from @datawrestler ...

Comment: @MaxU to_csv does not have `index` as a parameter. I did read his reply. I solved it by `read_csv('file.csv', index=0)`

Comment: @Cheng, what is your Pandas version?

Comment: @Cheng, i could check only back to Pandas version 0.7.0 - it's already had `index` parameter - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: @MaxU you are right, my fault

Comment: @datawrestler thank you, I was focusing too much on reading from csv and never thought it was the write operation giving me trouble

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In summary, what you're doing is saving the index to file and when you're reading back from the file, the column previously saved as `index` is loaded as a regular column.

There are a few ways to deal with this:

*Method 1*

When saving a `pandas.DataFrame` to disk, use `index=False` like this:

```
df.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

*Method 2*

When reading from file, you can define the column that is to be used as index, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col='index')
```

*Method 3*

If method #2 does not suit you for some reason, you can always set the column to be used as index later on, like this:

```
df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
```

After this point, your datafame should look like this:

```
        userid    locale    age
index
    0    A1092     EN-US     31
    1    B9032     SV-SE     23
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Either don't write index when saving DataFrame to CSV file (`df.to_csv('...', index=False)`) or if you have to deal with CSV files, which you can't change/edit, use `usecols` parameter:

```
A = pd.read_csv('/path/to/fileA.csv', usecols=['userid','locale'])
```

in order to get rid of the `Unnamed:0` column ...