# Remove Unnamed columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data file from columns A-G like below but when I am reading it with `pd.read_csv('data.csv')` it prints an extra `unnamed` column at the end for no reason.

```
colA    ColB    colC    colD    colE    colF    colG    Unnamed: 7
44      45      26      26      40      26      46        NaN
47      16      38      47      48      22      37        NaN
19      28      36      18      40      18      46        NaN
50      14      12      33      12      44      23        NaN
39      47      16      42      33      48      38        NaN
```

I have seen my data file various times but I have no extra data in any other column. How I should remove this extra column while reading ? Thanks

Comment: Your first column is probably the index col see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519086/pandas-how-to-get-rid-of-unnamed-column-in-a-dataframe

Comment: I just had the same issue. I examined my data file.. and found that there was an extra separator at the end of the header row (row 0).

Answer (score 338, accepted):

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

In [162]: df
Out[162]:
   colA  ColB  colC  colD  colE  colF  colG
0    44    45    26    26    40    26    46
1    47    16    38    47    48    22    37
2    19    28    36    18    40    18    46
3    50    14    12    33    12    44    23
4    39    47    16    42    33    48    38
```

---

**NOTE:** very often there is only one unnamed column `Unnamed: 0`, which is the first column in the CSV file. This is the result of the following steps:

1. a DataFrame is saved into a CSV file using parameter `index=True`, which is the **default** behaviour
2. we read this CSV file into a DataFrame using `pd.read_csv()` without explicitly specifying `index_col=0` (default: `index_col=None`)

The easiest way to get rid of this column is to specify the parameter `pd.read_csv(..., index_col=0)`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
```

Comment: For some reason, the above response was unsuccessful in my case, but this [link](https://www.datasciencelearner.com/drop-unnamed-column-pandas/)  resolved it for me. Using **match**  instead of  **contains**                                                       
 `df2.loc[:,~df2.columns.str.match("Unnamed")]`

Comment: The `index_col=0` comment is very useful - most occurrences of Unnamed columns are for "Unnamed: 0", which is likely to be an index. Although not the case in this question.

Answer (score 38):

First, find the columns that have 'unnamed', then drop those columns. Note: You should Add `inplace = True` to the `.drop` parameters as well.

```
df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 15):

The [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) function removes [missing values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) (e.g. `NaN`, `NaT`).

For example the following code would remove any columns from your dataframe, where all of the elements of that column are missing.

```
df.dropna(how='all', axis='columns')
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The approved solution doesn't work in my case, so my solution is the following one:

```
    ''' The column name in the example case is "Unnamed: 7"
 but it works with any other name ("Unnamed: 0" for example). '''

        df.rename({"Unnamed: 7":"a"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)

        # Then, drop the column as usual.

        df.drop(["a"], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Hope it helps others.