# Drop columns with no header on csv import with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here is a sample csv:

```
|  Header A |      | Unnamed: 1 |  Header D |
|-----------|------|------------|-----------|
| a1        | b1   | c1         | d1        |
| a2        | b2   | c2         | d2        |
```

If I import it with `pandas.read_csv`, it turns into this:

```
  Header A Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 1.1 Header D
0      a1         b1           c1       d1
1      a2         b2           c2       d2
```

My goal is dropping all the columns with empty headers, in this case the second column, but I cannot use the assigned column names by pandas to filter them, because there might also be non-empty columns starting with `Unnamed`, like the third column in the example.

Columns are not known before hand, so I do not have any control over them.

I have tried the following args with `read_csv`, but have not had any luck with them:

- `prefix`: it just does not work!
- `usecols`: Empty headers already have a name when they are passed to `usecols`, which makes it unusable to me.

I have looked at some other answers on SO, like the ones below, but none of them cover my case:

[How to get rid of `Unnamed:` column in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519086/how-to-get-rid-of-unnamed-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

[Remove Unnamed columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983622/remove-unnamed-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You have a column in the CSV file with a name `Unnamed: 1` that you want to keep? Are you writing this CSV file beforehand?

Comment: The might be a column in the csv starting with `Unnamed`m but I do not know before hand. I would like to cover all possible cases.

Comment: why you named your csv columns like this ...`Unnamed: 1`

Comment: @Wen-Ben I didn't. It's an example that shows it's possible to have such column names!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to "peek" at the headers beforehand and get the indices of non-empty headers. Then it's not a case of dropping them, but not including them in the original df.

```
import csv

import pandas as pd

with open('test.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    headers = next(reader)

header_indices = [i for i, item in enumerate(headers) if item]

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', usecols=header_indices)
```

Comment: Thanks. That was short and efficient.

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks mate, took a while to get there :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Read your columns to list with df.columns
2. create a tf_list with True/False based on your logic (search for None, Unnamed etc)
3. filter_df = df.loc[:, tf_list]

Comment: This wouldn't work. The damage would already have been done because Pandas would have filled the blank columns with "Unnamed: x" and it would be indistinguishable from a column that also shared that style of name in the file