# Pandas expression causes column explosion (or how to delete columns that contain substring in duplicate names environment)

Tags: pandas

I use the following pandas expression

```
df = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed:')]]
```

to drop columns that contain Unnamed. I got this one from here 
[Remove Unnamed columns in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983622/remove-unnamed-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/43983654)

For some reason, in some cases, this line causes an explosion of columns 
e.g

```
df shape in (2000, 1451)
after dropping Unnamed (2000, 3851)
```

in particular, it seems like it causes an explosion in case some columns have the same name e.g duplicates.

Anyone knows why this happens and how to avoid it?

How do I drop columns that have certain substring in duplicate-name-allowed case? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're slicing with names of columns when you clearly have repeated names.  You want to slice using `loc` and a boolean mask.

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed:')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am recommended fixing the duplicated columns problem

```
s=df.columns.to_series()
s1=s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str)
newc=s+s1.mask(s1=='0','')
Out[717]: 
a     a
a    a1
b     b
dtype: object
df.columns=newc
```

Comment: @YohanRoth adding a name count if unique nothing change, if duplicated adding the the count number to make it unique