# how to drop columns missing column names AND data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

So, I read CSV-files that are generated using excel.
Those can contain empty columns and rows on the right side - resp. below the data range/table.
Empty here meaning really empty. So: No column header, no data whatsoever, clearly an artifact.

In a first iteration I just used

```
pd.read_csv().dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=False).dropna(axis='index', how='all', inplace=False)
```

which seemed to work fine.
But it also removes correctly empty columns. Correctly empty here meaning regular columns including a column name, that are really supposed to be empty because that is their data.

I do want to keep all columns that
have a proper column name OR contain data -> someone might have just forgotten to give a column name, but it is a proper column

So, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983654/2215053 I first used

```
unnamed_cols_mask = basedata_df2.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')
basedata_df2.loc[:, ~unnamed_cols_mask] + basedata_df2.loc[:, unnamed_cols_mask].dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=False)
```

which looks and feels clean, but it scrambles the column order.

So now I go with:

```
df = pd.read_csv().dropna(axis='index', how='all', inplace=False)
df = df[[column_name for column_name in df.columns.array if not column_name.startswith('Unnamed: ') or not df[column_name].isnull().all()]]
```

Which works.
But there should be an obviously right way to accomplish this frequently occuring task?
So how could I do this better?

Specifically: Is there a way to make sure the column names starting with 'Unnamed: ' were created by the `pd.read_csv()` and not originally imported from the csv?

Comment: I guess the line `df = [[column_name for column_name in df.columns.array if not column_name.startswith('Unnamed: ') or not df[column_name].isnull().all()]]` should actually read `df = df[[` right? but that doesn't really drop the column, it just creates a slice object which is something like a view on the existing dataframe and behaves a bit different (not all operations are supported by slices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think there is no built-in function. Also not in `pandas.read_csv`. But you can apply the following code:

```
# get all rows which contain only nas
ser_all_na= df.isna().all(axis='rows')
# get all rows which got a generic name Unnamed...
del_indexer= ser_all_na.index.str.startswith('Unnamed: ')
# now delete all columns which got no explicit name and only contain nas
del_indexer&= ser_all_na
df.drop(columns=ser_all_na[del_indexer].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works and I think I even understand how :)