# pandas read excel without unnamed columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Trying to read excel table that looks like this:

|  | **B** | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | data | data |
| data | data | data |

but read excel doesn't recognizes that one column doesn't start from first row and it reads like this:

| Unnamed : 0 | **B** | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | data | data |
| data | data | data |

Is there a way to read data like i need? I have checked parameters like header = but thats not what i need.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked/solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983622/remove-unnamed-columns-in-pandas-dataframe). So basically the easiest thing would be to either drop the first column (if thats always the problematic column) with

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
```

or remove the unnamed column via

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but i dont need to delete column, basically table i need to read has columns of different heights like i showed (A is a start of column just like B, C) so table is not pure rectangle and i cant find the way to either read or massage dataframe to be like it is in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip automatic column labeling with something like `pd.read_excel(..., header=None)`

This will skip random labeling.

Then you can use more elaborate computation (e.g. first non empty value) to get the labels such as
`df.apply(lambda s: s.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)[0])`