# Pandas .drop Function for unnamed columns does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to drop a unnamed column from a dataframe created from a Xlsx but it won't drop.

```
def create_final_table(self):
    self.raw_data_tables["sales_codes"] = self.raw_data_tables["sales_codes"].drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
    self.raw_data_tables["vehicle_hash"] = self.raw_data_tables["vehicle_hash"].drop(
        columns=['Unnamed: 0', 'record_source', 'load_ts'])
```

When I execute this code it doesnt drop the Unnamed column. If I delete the ".drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])" command I get the same result as with this command.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983622/remove-unnamed-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)?

Comment: Yes I have checked this but unfortunetly it doesnt work for me

Comment: And this: `df2.loc[:,~df2.columns.str.match("Unnamed")]`? (taken from the same page just from a comment)

Comment: no that is not working either, I really dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 def create_final_table(self):
        self.raw_data_tables["sales_codes"] = self.raw_data_tables["sales_codes"].drop('Unnamed: 0', axis='columns')
        self.raw_data_tables["vehicle_hash"] = self.raw_data_tables["vehicle_hash"].drop(['Unnamed: 0', 'record_source', 'load_ts'], axis='columns')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).