# How to fix a blank column being added at the far left when reading my excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-3.7

I'm working on a rather large excel file and as part of it I'd like to insert two columns into a new excel file at the far right which works, however whenever I do so an unnamed column appears at the far left with numbers in it.

This is for an excel file, and I've tried to use the .drop feature as well as use a new file and read about the CSV files but I cannot seem to apply it here, so nothing seems to solve it.

```
wdf = pd.read_excel(tLoc)

sheet_wdf_map = pd.read_excel(tLoc, sheet_name=None)


wdf['Adequate'] = np.nan
wdf['Explanation'] = np.nan

wdf = wdf.drop(" ", axis=1)
```

I expect the output to be my original columns with only the two new columns being on the far right without the unnamed column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid of "Unnamed: 0" column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519086/how-to-get-rid-of-unnamed-0-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @AmitAmola Very similar solution, although that is for CSV files and read_csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `index_col=[0]` as an argument to `read_excel`.