# Pandas delete column/columns and then store/export new csv file at the same path

Tags: python, pandas

I am encountering a scenario where deleting/update columns of a pandas dataframe is required. What I get as a result is that the columns I am trying to delete, get deleted but when I export a new CSV file from the dataframe, I see new columns added that have the same data + data types of the columns I deleted. These new columns have names like `Unnamed :0`, `Unnamed: 0.1`, `Unnamed: 0.1.1`, etc.

Here is the snippet that represents the procedure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./<some_file>.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')
del df['col']
df.to_csv('./<some_file>.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('./<some_file>.csv', encoding='unicode_escape')
```

Any ideas why I am encountering such a situation and whether what I am doing is correct?

Comment: In addition to Anurag's `to_csv` answer, you can also specify the `index_col` on `read_csv`: see [How to get rid of “Unnamed: 0” column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358758/13138364)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly this is because you are storing index in your csv file and after saving and loading that file it makes a new index and the previous index is turned into names like `Unnamed :0, Unnamed: 0.1, Unnamed: 0.1.1`

so to solve this just pass `index` parameter in `to_csv()` method and set that equal to `False`:-

```
df.to_csv('./<some_file>.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: I checked github issues of Pandas and I got it working, made your answer the correct one for other visitors.